# Rotativa Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, rotativa

## problem

I am trying to create pdf in asp.net core using Rotativa but it throw me an error.
I want to create html and convert it to pdf and then store in on server directory

## Error

[image]

## code

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Index(Invoice invoice)
    {
        var webRoot = _env.WebRootPath;

        var pdf = new ViewAsPdf("Index")
        {
            FileName = "Test.pdf",
            PageSize = Rotativa.AspNetCore.Options.Size.A4,
            PageOrientation = Rotativa.AspNetCore.Options.Orientation.Portrait,
            PageHeight = 20,
            
        };

        var byteArray = pdf.BuildFile(ControllerContext).Result;
        //var fileStream = new MemoryStream(Path.Combine(webRoot, pdf.FileName), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Answer

The error indicates that you haven't configured Rotativa.

Configuration your application like this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
    Rotativa.AspNetCore.RotativaConfiguration.Setup(env);
}
```

Also add `wkhtmltopdf.exe` to wwwroot like this:

```
wwwroot
    Rotativa
        wkhtmltopdf.exe
```

Once you have done that, the following will work.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var pdf = new Rotativa.AspNetCore.ViewAsPdf("Index")
    {
        FileName = "C:\\Test.pdf",
        PageSize = Rotativa.AspNetCore.Options.Size.A4,
        PageOrientation = Rotativa.AspNetCore.Options.Orientation.Portrait,
        PageHeight = 20,
    };

    var byteArray = await pdf.BuildFile(ControllerContext);
    return File(byteArray, "application/pdf");
}
```

Note the use of `async/await` instead of using `.Result`.

## See also:

- Needs Configuration section here https://github.com/webgio/Rotativa.AspNetCore
- GitHub demo here https://github.com/shaunluttin/asp-net-core-rotativa-pdf
- Download of wkhtmltopdf here https://wkhtmltopdf.org/